# Ran out of inodes - 100% Full

Tags: filesystem, disk-usage, inode

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 on AWS EC2 instance which has been working fine until this problem.

My problem is that I've used 100% of available inodes, as I discovered with this command:

```
$ df -i
Filesystem     Inodes  IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev           124464    360 124104    1% /dev
tmpfs          126787    449 126338    1% /run
/dev/xvda1     524288 522638   1650  100% /
tmpfs          126787      1 126786    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs          126787      5 126782    1% /run/lock
tmpfs          126787     16 126771    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs          126793      4 126789    1% /run/user/1000
```

The main culprits I discovered:

```
$ find / -xdev -printf '%h\n' | sort | uniq -c | sort -k 1 -n
   1155 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-62/include/linux
   1155 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-65/include/linux
   1155 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-66/include/linux
   1155 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-70/include/linux
   1155 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-71/include/linux
   1155 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-72/include/linux
   1155 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-75/include/linux
   1155 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-78/include/linux
   1155 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-79/include/linux
   1155 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-81/include/linux
   1155 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-83/include/linux
   1155 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-87/include/linux
   1155 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-89/include/linux
   1155 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-91/include/linux
   1155 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-92/include/linux
   1514 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-62-generic/include/config
   1516 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-65-generic/include/config
   1516 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-66-generic/include/config
   1516 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-70-generic/include/config
   1516 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-71-generic/include/config
   1516 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-72-generic/include/config
   1516 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-75-generic/include/config
   1517 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-78-generic/include/config
   1517 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-79-generic/include/config
   1517 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-81-generic/include/config
   1517 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-83-generic/include/config
   1517 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-87-generic/include/config
   1517 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-89-generic/include/config
   1517 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-91-generic/include/config
   1517 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-92-generic/include/config
   1517 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-93-generic/include/config
```

Is it safe to delete these files, and if yes could you please tell me the exact command or commands to use on my PuTTY client?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65189/discussion-on-question-by-muzz-ran-out-of-inodes-100-full).

Answer (score 3):

About removing older kernels: you may use command `sudo apt-get autoremove`, which removes stuff you installed, but is not needed any more (like old kernels or dependencies of software you removed later).

About finding the culprit of your inode use, you could use du to find out where they went, like so: `du -s --inodes /*`. It will tell you the inode use of directories and files found in /; note, though, that directiries and files, that start in a dot, won't get included in this search, because theis is how * works. There are many ways to get around this, one would go like this: `du -s --inodes $(find / -maxdepth 1)`. You continue your exploring by replacing / with those directories, where you find too many inodes used.

TomTomTom

Comment: it's a good idea to append `2>/dev/null` to these commands, otherwise the results tend to be hard to pick out between all the perms errors. Or you can run with `sudo`, but even then some locations are inaccessible