# Mkdir and all command - No space left on device

Tags: 18.04

I am using ubuntu 18.04 bionic.

I'am getting errors like this with every command.

for example I got this error for the "mkdir" command.

> mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/lib/apt/lists’: No space left on
> device

I can not run any command.

I did a lot of research on the internet. none of them worked for me.

My disk status:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs           395M  656K  394M   1% /run
/dev/vda1        78G   14G   65G  17% /
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda15      105M  3.6M  101M   4% /boot/efi
tmpfs           395M     0  395M   0% /run/user/0
```

> df -hi

```
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev             490K   384  490K    1% /dev
tmpfs            494K   631  493K    1% /run
/dev/vda1        9.9M  9.9M     0  100% /
tmpfs            494K     1  494K    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            494K     4  494K    1% /run/lock
tmpfs            494K    18  494K    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda15          0     0     0     - /boot/efi
tmpfs            494K    11  494K    1% /run/user/0
```

> du

```
4   ./.config/htop
8   ./.config
4   ./.gnupg/private-keys-v1.d
8   ./.gnupg
4   ./vst_install_backups/1553954077/clamd
4   ./vst_install_backups/1553954077/spamassassin
4   ./vst_install_backups/1553954077/bind
4   ./vst_install_backups/1553954077/postgresql
4   ./vst_install_backups/1553954077/proftpd
4   ./vst_install_backups/1553954077/mysql
4   ./vst_install_backups/1553954077/apache2
4   ./vst_install_backups/1553954077/dovecot
4   ./vst_install_backups/1553954077/exim4
4   ./vst_install_backups/1553954077/vsftpd
4   ./vst_install_backups/1553954077/nginx
4   ./vst_install_backups/1553954077/vesta
4   ./vst_install_backups/1553954077/mongodb
4   ./vst_install_backups/1553954077/php
60  ./vst_install_backups/1553954077
64  ./vst_install_backups
27564   ./.cache/composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org
27568   ./.cache/composer/repo
124 ./.cache/composer/vcs/https---github.com-bluerhinos-phpMQTT.git/objects/pack
4   ./.cache/composer/vcs/https---github.com-bluerhinos-phpMQTT.git/objects/info
132 ./.cache/composer/vcs/https---github.com-bluerhinos-phpMQTT.git/objects
4   ./.cache/composer/vcs/https---github.com-bluerhinos-phpMQTT.git/branches
4   ./.cache/composer/vcs/https---github.com-bluerhinos-phpMQTT.git/refs/heads
4   ./.cache/composer/vcs/https---github.com-bluerhinos-phpMQTT.git/refs/tags
12  ./.cache/composer/vcs/https---github.com-bluerhinos-phpMQTT.git/refs
52  ./.cache/composer/vcs/https---github.com-bluerhinos-phpMQTT.git/hooks
8   ./.cache/composer/vcs/https---github.com-bluerhinos-phpMQTT.git/info
228 ./.cache/composer/vcs/https---github.com-bluerhinos-phpMQTT.git
232 ./.cache/composer/vcs
4   ./.cache/composer/files
27812   ./.cache/composer
27816   ./.cache
4   ./.local/share/nano
8   ./.local/share
12  ./.local
16  ./.composer
4   ./.ssh
27964   .
```

Comment: try `df -hi` , ie. do you have inodes available? or are they all used up?

Comment: [screenshot](https://ibb.co/2Zpkm3g)

Comment: Please don't provide pictures of text, you can edit your own questions and add details there.  It shows though you're out of disk space.  Inodes are created at format time (most of us just using defaults).  You've got something on your system that's created tons of really tiny files that has used all inodes, so no more files can be created...   `du` will allow you to find your cause..  (so you can `rm` the culprit)

Comment: I am using digitalocean web console. it doesn't allow c / p. I updated the question. I am not sure. Maybe it can be problem.

Comment: Should I delete all the files resulting from `du`?

Comment: Sorry I assumed you'd be able to work it out from there (*also that I'd find a duplicate, sorry I can't find one, I'm assuming another user here will as I'm off to bed*).  `du` (disk usage) will need to be told to look for inodes, ie. option `--inodes` is required.  You hunt for a directory that's got likely millions of files in it... either you are using buggy software, or have a mis-configuration causing tons of tiny files to be created.  `rm` will fix the issue yes, but when you find it you still need to fix the cause or it'll happen again & you'll be repeating this process again & again...

Comment: That depends on the `du` you're using, but I'd say: NO. Try to find small files with `find / -size 0c`, where you increase 0c by one each time. (1c, 2c, 3c, but **do read** the manual, 1b, 2b are possible too). I agree with @guiverc that you are likely to find many. THEN, you need to find out where they came from and if the process making them is terminated. Then, with `find`, it would be easy to do a `-delete`, but PLEASE **do read the man page** for find (`man find`).

Comment: Sorry @guiverc, I was typing at the same time you were.

Comment: what they said did not work for me. [askubuntu.com/questions/953227/ran-out-of-inodes-100-full](http://askubuntu.com/questions/953227/ran-out-of-inodes-100-full)